# Jackson Databind 2.8.x Behaviour Change

Tags: jackson, lombok, jackson-databind

I am using lombok.Builder.Default to set default values and trying to deserialize json object using jackson. In jackson 2.6.x, it was calling NoArgsContructor of the object during deserialization and from jackson 2.8.x it has stopped calling that constructor. Is there a possible way to fix to get back to the default behaviour on 2.8.x version.

Comment: I don't see any indication in the Jackson changelog that such a significant change happened. Are you sure it is nothing else that caused the different behavior? I'm also wondering what the builder has to do with this, because if you'd use the builder with Jackson, it never should have called the no-args constructor of the class, just the one of the builder.

Comment: Yeah. I was able to figure out that if @AllArgsConstructor is used and empty Constructor is written, it used to call empty Constructor in 2.6.x but not in 2.8.x. Solution was to suppressConstructorProperties in lombok.config file.